# Extend app storage

Tags: applications, storage

Is it possible to expand or change app storage limit on Android?

In this specific case (*see pictures below*) it says that I have more than 1.4 GB free, but when trying to install apps message appears that there isn't enough free space. Why is this happening?

Default storage location is SD card.

[image: Screenshot from storage settings]
[image: Internal storage]

Comment: Is this the internal or external SD card?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab External sd card 2Gb

Comment: Does your phone also have an internal sd card? That's the location apps will be installed to.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab edited the question with internal storage screenshot